# Avoid Select-Object output on screen

Tags: powershell

I am having a bit of trouble with Select-Object.

With the following piece of (truncated) code:

```
$totalData=(Get-Content $Env:TEMP\FBIUtemp2.txt)
.....
$data=""
....
....
$data =($totalData | Select-Object -Index ($s..$limit))
$data.Replace("`r`n"," ")
$data.Replace("`n"," ")
```

I get a String (list of String separated with newline termination) from a file and get lines between $s and $limit into another $data String.

The code work as expected except that Select-Object keeps showing result on the screen and I would like for it not to do that.
I tried multiple things, but it either ends up doing nothing or stopping the script. I tried to mute the result with Out-Null, but then it doesn't fill the $data variable. Is there a parameter that I am missing?

Also, I don't want to split the $totalData String in a list to reassemble it later, as it would slow down the whole process.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) that produces visible output, it is your `` $data.Replace("`r`n"," ") `` and `` $data.Replace("`n"," ") `` method calls, both of which *output the result* of the string replacement - rather than modifying the input string(s) *in place* (something that is fundamentally unsupported, given that .NET strings are *immutable*).

`$data` contains an *array of lines*, whose elements by definition do *not* have embedded newlines (whether in the form of `` `n `` (LF) or `` `r`n `` (CRLF)).

If your intent is to join those lines with spaces:

```bash
$data = $data -join ' '
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Indeed your are correct, the $data.Replace( was the culprit.
Thank you for your help!